# if statement with char condition in C

Tags: c

I have been working on a college project. I want user to enter Y/N if he wants to continue or not, so I wrote following code

```
    repeat: 
    pr=0;
    q=0;
    res=0;
    printf("\nEnter the serial number of product you wish to purchase: ");
    scanf("%d",&pr);
    printf("Quantity: ");
    scanf("%d",&q);
    billing(pr,q);
    printf("Continue Shopping? (y/n) ");
    scanf("%d",&res);
    if(res=='y')
    goto repeat;
    else
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is entering y executes else statement. I tried replacing y with 1,2,3.... and it works but I want it to work with Y or y or yes.

Comment: Just input `121` for the `scanf()` after the `printf("Continue Shopping? (y/n) ");`.

Comment: Please, do not abuse `goto` statement

Comment: scanf("%c",&res);

Comment: What do you mean by abusing goto statement @OrkhanAlikhanov?Do you suggest any alternative?

Comment: Yes. Use `while` or similar

Comment: @arun483: What kind of maniac teaches about `goto` before `for` or `[do] while`?

Comment: `char res[4];` ... `scanf("%3s", res);`...`if(*res == 'Y' || *res == 'y')`

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by "I tried replacing y with 1,2,3.... and it works". How does it work??

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov `scanf(" %c",&res);` with a space otherwise will read the `newline` left in buffer.

Comment: No [mcve], see [ask]. And - as a beginner - do not use `goto`! Learn about loops! (Disclaimer for the `goto` fans: it has it's usa-cases, but this is none of them and a beginner first should learn to crouch before trying to run.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in this line

```
scanf("%d",&res);
```

It should be

```
scanf(" %c",&res);
```

The formatting placeholders for char is `%c` not `%d`

Comment: for this I should also define "char res;" ?

Comment: @arun483 It's best to always define your variables explicitly in the type you want.

Comment: Yes you should.

Comment: Please put a `space` in front of the format `%c` as `scanf(" %c",&res);` otherwise this answer will read the `newline` which was still in the buffer. Fixed one bug but introduced another.

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry. Edited.

Comment: Also, `res` has to be a `char`. This answer won't work if OP declared `res` as `int`.

Answer (score -1):

```
scanf("%d",&res);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c",&res);
```

As suggested by multiple users do while should be used over goto, so better code would be

```
    do{
    pr=0;
    q=0;
    printf("\nEnter the serial number of product you wish to purchase: ");
    scanf("%d",&pr);
    printf("Quantity: ");
    scanf("%d",&q);
    billing(pr,q);
    printf("Continue Shopping? (y/n) ");
    scanf(" %c",&res);
    }
    while(*res == 'Y' || *res == 'y');
    return 0;
}
```

Also res should also be declared `char res;`

Comment: The downvoter really should have explained their downvote. This is incorrect: `while(*res == 'Y' || *res == 'y');`. Assuming `res` is declared as `char res;` then it should be `while(res == 'Y' || res == 'y');`. (No `*` in front of `res`).

Comment: You're not really adding anything by choosing do ... while over goto. It's still a structured program. Goto only destroys structure when you jump into or out of a block.

Comment: In this case, the `do..while` block is perfectly warranted. Especially combined with proper indentation, it will make it more apparent what part of the code is looping, and it is easy to see which condition is used to continue the loop.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean He's adding a best practice. I'm not one those rabid anti-goto people; I do think `goto` has its place and when it's the appropriate control mechanism it should be used.But it should _never_ be chosen as a loop mechanism unless there's a compelling reason to do so, and in my 30 years of programming experience I have seen exactly one such algorithm. It's a rare day that replacing a `do`, `while` or `for` with `goto` makes sense.